# Adding Panel in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, customization

Following is a demo of a CTI connector for dynamics CRM 2011:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkLu-2TPhu8&feature=youtu.be

Does anyone has any idea that how the CTI control panel on the right of every CRM page might have been added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think they are dynamically adding the panel to the page through scripts loaded for their custom ribbon button.

Comment: I agree, probably loaded into the container used for dynamic help. Worth noting that it would be a completely unsupported customisation